# Javascript - Outputting values of array

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have a simple JavaScript array of image SRC values,

I gather the image src attributes like so building up an array:

```
    var imgSrc = [];
    $('.monelem_controls_imageControl_container img').each(function () {
        imgSrc.push($(this).attr("src"));
    });
```

I then need to output the array of images in the following format:
    ['images/fullscreen/image1.jpg','images/fullscreen/image2.jpg','images/fullscreen/image3.jpg'];

How can I output my array in this way?

Comment: Do you mean you need to send that data somewhere or display it as part of your page?

Comment: Im using the array of images with a lightbox plugin.

Comment: My guess is that wherever the plugin is looking for the format you mention above it actually wants the array defined by it (which is what you already have).

Comment: Afraid not David, already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON:

```
JSON.stringify( myArray );
```

Comment: Because? How will it look? Can you improve on this answer a bit for someone stumbling on it later? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your array only contains primitive types (like strings), you can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and add the square brackets:

```
var images = [
   "images/fullscreen/image1.jpg",
   "images/fullscreen/image2.jpg",
   "images/fullscreen/image3.jpg"
];
var serialized = "[" + images.toString() + "]";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [
    'images/fullscreen/image1.jpg',
    'images/fullscreen/image2.jpg',
    'images/fullscreen/image3.jpg'
];
var strArray = "['" + arr.join("','") + "']";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick try this JS Fiddle, though by the time i'd done this @Innuendo has got a more neater answer!

http://jsfiddle.net/7vCFa/